# Remove programmatically UILabel after adding - swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uilabel

I have made a UIView and two UILabels programmatically. The labels say something like: "There are no posts, follow someone to add to your feed.".

`self.update.count` shows the number of posts to show. So if it is `0` is should show the labels that I made. If not it should not show any of the labels.

I have made this code but it wont remove the labels and the UIView again? it is inside the `viewWillAppear`:

```
if self.updates.count == 0 {

            print("THERE ARE NO POSTS: \(self.updates.count)")
            self.tableView.addSubview(self.noPostView)
            self.tableView.addSubview(self.noPostLabel)
            self.tableView.addSubview(self.noPostText)

            //noPostView.anchorToTop(view.topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: nil)
            self.noPostView.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.tableView.centerXAnchor).active = true
            //noPostView.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(tableView.centerYAnchor).active = true
            self.noPostView.anchor(self.view.topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: 80, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: self.view.frame.width, heightConstant: self.noPostLabel.frame.height + self.noPostText.frame.height)

            self.noPostLabel.anchor(self.view.topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: 80, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: self.noPostView.frame.width, heightConstant: 50)
            self.noPostLabel.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.noPostView.centerXAnchor).active = true


            self.noPostText.anchor(self.noPostLabel.bottomAnchor, left: self.noPostView.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: self.noPostView.rightAnchor, topConstant: -20, leftConstant: 35, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 35)
            self.noPostText.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(60).active = true
            self.noPostText.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.noPostView.centerXAnchor).active = true

            self.loadingSpinner.stopAnimating()
        } else {
            print("THERE ARE: \(self.updates.count) POSTS")

            self.tableView.willRemoveSubview(self.noPostView)
            self.tableView.willRemoveSubview(self.noPostText)
            self.tableView.willRemoveSubview(self.noPostLabel)

        }
```

Comment: Just hide the labels when you don't need them i.e "self.noPostLabel.isHidden = true" and show them when needed.

Comment: Worked like a charm @DrPatience :D stupid me........

Comment: Try this self.noPostLabel.removeFromSuperview(), I hope this helps you

Comment: :) that happens to everyone. Ill add my comment as an answer. Please vote. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just hide the labels when you don't need them i.e "self.noPostLabel.isHidden = true" and show them when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [willRemoveSubview(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622647-willremovesubview) which apple describes below.

> The default implementation of this method does nothing. Subclasses can
>   override it to perform additional actions whenever subviews are
>   removed. This method is called when the subview’s superview changes or
>   when the subview is removed from the view hierarchy completely.